# Number of planted plane trees on n+1 vertices

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of planted plane trees on $n+1$ vertices, such that every vertex adjacent to the root has degree m?

I am working on this problem and trying to figure out what the generating function is so I can count the number of such trees.

For every $n$ the sequence of possible values for $m$ is from $1,2, ...,n$. So I am thinking this will be a double sum, depending on both $n$ and $m$.

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{n}p_{m}x^m$.

When $m=1$ we will have the root and $n$ vertices adjacent to it.
When $m=2$ we will have the root a vertex adjacent to the root and to some other PPT, or there will be two vertices adjacent to the root and both of them adjacent to some PPT and so on,
when $m=n$ we will have the root and $n$ one vertex adjacent to the root and to $n$ other edges.

I am not sure if my thinking is right, or if it is how to put everything together.

Answer (score 1):

The number of PPTs on $n+1$ vertices where the root has degree $k$ is given by [OEIS A033184](https://oeis.org/A033184):
$$T_{n,k}=\frac k{2n-k}\binom{2n-k}n$$
An admissible PPT for given $n,m$ can be split into the root and $k$ sub-PPTs with at least $m$ vertices each and roots having $m-1$ children (hence degree $m$). Generating the required "thick" partitions is an easy matter of stars and bars; we then compute $T_{n-1,m-1}$ for each part of each partition, take the product over each partition anf finally sum. This Python script implements the procedure:

```
from math import comb, prod
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr

def ct(n,k): #|PPTs on n+1 verts where root has degree k|
 return comb(2*n-k,n)*k//(2*n-k)

for n in range(1,16):
 l = []
 for m in range(1,n+1):
  if m == 1:
   l.append(1)
   continue
  # children of root form roots of PPTs with degree m-1
  # so n must be split into k parts of size at least m
  t = 0
  maxk = n//m
  for k in range(1,maxk+1):
   stars = n-k*m
   for cmb in cwr(range(stars+1),k-1):
    bars = (0,) + cmb + (stars,)
    t += prod([ct(bars[i+1]-bars[i]+m-1,m-1) for i in range(k)])
  l.append(t)
 print(n, l)
```

It produces this triangle where $n$ precedes its corresponding row and $m$ increases left-to-right in each row from $1$ to $n$:

```
1 [1]
2 [1, 1]
3 [1, 1, 1]
4 [1, 3, 2, 1]
5 [1, 7, 5, 3, 1]
6 [1, 20, 15, 9, 4, 1]
7 [1, 59, 46, 28, 14, 5, 1]
8 [1, 184, 146, 91, 48, 20, 6, 1]
9 [1, 593, 478, 303, 165, 75, 27, 7, 1]
10 [1, 1964, 1601, 1028, 573, 275, 110, 35, 8, 1]
11 [1, 6642, 5461, 3542, 2010, 1001, 429, 154, 44, 9, 1]
12 [1, 22845, 18909, 12364, 7116, 3641, 1638, 637, 208, 54, 10, 1]
13 [1, 79667, 66295, 43637, 25402, 13270, 6188, 2548, 910, 273, 65, 11, 1]
14 [1, 281037, 234888, 155468, 91350, 48515, 23257, 9996, 3808, 1260, 350, 77, 12, 1]
15 [1, 1001092, 839737, 558417, 330685, 178000, 87222, 38760, 15504, 5508, 1700, 440, 90, 13, 1]
```

Column 2 is [A030238](https://oeis.org/A030238). Column $m$ can be generated as follows:

- Let $c(x)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$ be the generating function of the Catalan numbers, then define
  $$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{1-xyc(x)}$$
  The $x^ny^m$ coefficient in its expansion is the number of *sub*-PPTs on $n$ total vertices where the root has degree $m$, including the sub-PPT root and the edge from it to the overall root.
- Expand as a series in $y$ and take the $y^m$ coefficient $g(x)=x^mc^{m-1}(x)$. The generating function of column $m$ is
  $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty g^k(x)=\frac{g(x)}{1-g(x)}$$